# scala directly map fields of sequence elements

Tags: scala

I have a collection with elements that have a field `field1`. I want to get all `field1`s that are options of type `MyType`.

Currently this is my code.

`elems.map(_.field1).map {case Some(found: MyType) => found}`

I'm sure this can be done in a much nicer way.. It bugs me that I need to use map twice. Is there a way to do this with only one map/collect ?

EDIT: My code works. I'm just wondering if it can be done in a better (i.e. *shorter* or *prettier* way).

Comment: A "prettier" way would be to not mix different types in the same collection. Than you could just do `elems.flatMap(_.field1)`

Comment: @Dima is right. What is the exact type of your collection? Is there a way it could be `Seq[Option[MyType]]` instead?

Comment: The collection can contain elements of different types (although they all implement a common trait). This is not something that I can change. I ended up using my original solution, as it is still the most concise one.

Comment: @Tschösi if you provide your types of `seq` and `MyType` and it's parents, answers would be more exact

Answer (score 4):

`elems.flatMap(_.field1.collect { case x: MyType => x })`

Answer (score 2):

I believe utilising `.flatMap` may solve this issue for you

```scala
elems.flatMap(_.field1 match {
  case myType: MyType => Some(myType)
  case _              => None
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `iterator` before transforming the collection accumulates all the transformations into a single one so perhaps try

```
elems
  .iterator
  .flatMap(_.field1)
  .collect { case v: MyType => v }
  .toList
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `Seq` type is `case class` you can use pattern matching with one `collect` function like so (see `actual` seq):

```scala
case class MyTypeWrapper(field1: Option[MyType])
case class MyType(x: String)

val elems                 = Seq.empty[MyTypeWrapper]
val expected: Seq[MyType] = elems.map(_.field1).map{ case Some(found: MyType) => found }

val actual: Seq[MyType] = elems.collect{ case MyTypeWrapper(Some(mt: MyType)) => mt }
// expected and actual should contains the same elements
```